# Prove that there exists a Borel measurable function $h: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $g= h\circ f$.

Tags: measure-theory

Problem:

Suppose $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is Borel measurable. Define $\mathcal A$ to be the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing the sets $\{ x : f(x) > a\}$ for every $a \in \mathbb R$. Suppose $g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is measurable with respect to $\mathcal A$, which means that $\{x : g(x) > a\} \in \mathcal A$ for every $a \in \mathbb R$. Prove that there exists a Borel measurable function $h: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $g= h\circ f$.

What I've looked into so far:

I'm thinking $h = g\circ f^{-1}$. This would mean I would need to prove that for any Borel measurable set $B$, we have $h^{-1}(B) = f(g^{-1}(B))\in \mathcal B$. Since $g$ is $\mathcal A$-measurable, $g^{-1}(B) = A\in \mathcal A$. Can we say that since $f$ is Borel measurable, $\{x: f(x) > a\} \in \mathcal B$, and $\mathcal A \subset \mathcal B$? However, I'm not sure what I can say about $f(A)$ besides that I need it to be Borel measurable.

Should I approach this differently, or am I on the right track?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that $f$ has in general no inverse which means that the expression $h = g \circ f^{-1}$ is not well-defined.

Usually, the statement is proved using a monotone class argument:

1. Prove the claim if $g$ is of the form $g=1_A$ where $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is a Borel set. To this end, note that $A \in \mathcal{A}$ (as $g$ is $\mathcal{A}$-measurable) and that any set $A \in \mathcal{A}$ admits a representation of the form $$A = f^{-1}(B)$$ for some Borel set $B$; this follows directly from the definition of the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$: $$\mathcal{A} = \sigma\{\{x; f(x)>a\}; a \in \mathbb{R}\} = \{f^{-1}(B); B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\}.$$
2. Prove the claim for a step function $g$.
3. Consider $g \geq 0$ measurable. Approximate $g$ by step functions in order to deduce that the claim holds for $g$.
4. For arbitrary measurable $g$, write $g=g^+-g^-$ where $g^+$ ($g^-$) denotes the positive (negative) part of $g$.

The result is known as *factorization lemma* and is of importance in probability theory.

Comment: This is very helpful. Thanks saz.

Comment: +1, but where does the equality $$\sigma\{\{x; f(x)>a\}; a \in \mathbb{R}\} = \{f^{-1}(B); B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\}$$ follow from?

Comment: @jesterII That's a general result. If $\mathcal{G}$ is the generator of a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ (i.e. $\mathcal{G} \subseteq \mathcal{F}$ and $\sigma(\mathcal{G}) = \mathcal{F}$), then $f^{-1}(\mathcal{F}) = \sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal{G}))$. This means that a mapping $f: (\Omega,\mathcal{A}) \to (X,\mathcal{F})$ is measurable iff $f^{-1}(G) \in \mathcal{A}$ for all $G \in \mathcal{G}$. Here, we have $$\mathcal{G} := \{(a,\infty); a \in \mathbb{R}\}$$ which is a generator of the Borel sigma-algebra $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: I don't see the link between $f^{-1}(\mathcal F)$ and $\{f^{-1}(B)\mid B\in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)\}$. Indeed, I guess that here $\mathcal F=\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$. Then $f^{-1}(\mathcal F)=\{F\mid f(F)\in \mathcal F\}$ but this is not $\{f^{-1}(B)\mid B\in \mathcal B\}$.

Comment: @user657324 I don't see that I mentioned $\mathcal{F}$ or $f^{-1}(\mathcal{F})$ anywhere in my answer (neither did the OP). Anyway, $f^{-1}(\mathcal{F})$ is a short-hand for $f^{-1}(\mathcal{F})=\{f^{-1}(F); F \in \mathcal{F}\}$.

Comment: @saz: Not in your answer but just in the comment before my previous comment. Ok, so $f^{-1}(\mathcal F)$ for $\mathcal F$ a $\sigma -$algebra is not the same than $f^{-1}(F)$ for a set $F$, correct ? Never see this notation before... Thank you :)

Comment: @user657324 I see; sorry, it's been a while since I wrote the comments. It's a relatively standard notation and, if you think about it for a while, it's quite natural. It's just the family of preimages.