# Y is $\sigma (X)$-measurable, show $Y=f(X)$ $f$ a Borel function

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am working on the following question for my probability theory class:

> Let $X, Y$ be random variables on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F}, P)$ such that $Y$ is $\sigma (X)$-measurable. Show that there is a Borel-measurable function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ so that $Y=f(X)$.

My plan for this is the following. Let $\mathcal{M}$ be the class of all random variables of the form $f(X)$ where $f$ is a Borel function. Let $\mathcal{A}=\sigma(X).$ I will then show that $\mathcal{M}$ satisfies (i), (ii) and (iii) below:

> (i) If $f,g\in\mathcal{M}, \ a,b\in\mathbb{R},$ then $af+bg\in\mathcal{M}$.
>
> (ii) If $f_1\leq f_2 \leq f_3 \leq \dots$ is a sequence of functions in $\mathcal{M}$ and $f(\omega)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f_n(\omega)<\infty$ for each $\omega\in\Omega$, then $f\in\mathcal{M}$.
>
> (iii) $1_A \in \mathcal{M}$ for each $A\in \mathcal{A}.$

Once I show that $\mathcal{M}$ satisfies those three conditions by the Monotone Class Theorem I will have that $\mathcal{M}$ contains all $\sigma(\mathcal{A})=\mathcal{A}=\sigma(X)$-measurable functions. So in particular $Y$ is in $\mathcal{M}$.

So far I believe I have figured out why $\mathcal{M}$ satisfies (i) and (ii).

I believe (i) is satisfied because a constant multiple of a measurable function is measurable, and the sum of two measurable functions is measurable.

I believe that (ii) is satisfied because the $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ of a sequence of measurable functions is measurable and in this case since the limit exists we have that the $\liminf$ would equal the $\limsup$ would equal the limit.

Now what I am having trouble showing is that for each $A\in \sigma(X)=\mathcal{A}$, $1_A\in\mathcal{M}$

Any help or comments would be appreciated!

Comment: That is the content of the [Factorization Lemma](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_lemma)

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful. This link was pretty helpful for me because it didn't go straight to simple functions, it started with characteristic functions. https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Factorization_Lemma/Real-Valued_Function

Comment: See also this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/847387/